# Python script cannot find/see file when being executed through shell script

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, io

I am trying to run a Python script, `postprocess.py`, through a shell script, `Allrun.sh`.

It works fine when I execute the Python script manually, but I get an error when I run `Allrun.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: Allrun.sh 
python postprocess.py
```

And here is the short segment of `postprocess.py` that the error is thrown for

```
   for files in os.listdir("."):
       if files.endswith(".stl"):
           STLfile = files
   f = open(STLfile,'r')
```

The error:

> line 797, in PostProcessing
>       f = open(STLfile,'r') NameError: name 'STLfile' is not defined

However, an `.stl` file does exist in the directory.

Comment: Are the two scripts in the same folder that this "STLfile", and are you lauching the bash script from this same directory? You should really use an absolute path, or a path relative to the one in which resides your python script (which you can get by checking the `__file__` variable at the module level: `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` returns the directory your script resides in).

Comment: Is STLfile declared somewhere before the loop? If not, it seems like it might be a scope problem, although that doesn't explain why it works if you don't run it through the shell script.

Comment: @doukremt said what I was going to say, that you're probably executing the script from a different directory, hence `STLfile` is never defined because the if statement is false. Other tips: `files` should be renamed to `file`, and your program only works with the most recent `.stl` file it found, you may want to append the file to a list so you can keep track of all `.stl` files (in case more will exist later).

Comment: A `print os.getcwd()` can help.

Comment: My shell script is being executed from another path, but I cd to it. e.g. src/case/Allrun.sh  and src/PreProcessing/postprocessing.py       and the stl is in src/case/constant/triSurface/VarName.stl

Comment: Got it to work, I was going to the wrong directory.